# Set tab order in Mac app window

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm creating a login form that's loaded from a nib. I have several NSTextFields, but when the app is launched, the one that gains focus immediately is the last one I added to the form. How do I set up the tab order and change or remove the initial focus?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the Interface Builder: Right click on the NSTextField, link the nextKeyView with the object you want to be the next one that should be activated by pressing the "tab" button.
There's also an option called "Refuse First Responder". This option avoids the blue frame.